# Updating an Excel Radio Button based on the value of a web form

Tags: c#, excel, radio-button, excel-import

Currently I have a button on a C# web form that exports all of the user specified values to an Excel file using Aspose. Everything works great until I get to where I need to update a value of a radio button in Excel.

I tried a couple different methods... Below I'm trying to update the radio button as checked, it is located on the worksheet named _sheetSummary on the 6th tab.

```
Aspose.Cells.Worksheet _sheetSummary = _book.Worksheets[6];
_sheetSummary.Cells["B29"].Value = _Created;
_sheetSummary.CheckBoxes("obs2").Object.value = true;
```

"obs2" is the name of the radio button in the excel file. I don't know if i should be declaring that as a variable...

As I noted the excel "cells" update perfectly

Any assistance would be greatly welcomed....

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to use Aspose.Cells.Drawing.RadioButton object instead of CheckBox as you want to use/set option button. See the sample line of code for your reference:
e.g
**Sample code:**

```
Aspose.Cells.Worksheet _sheetSummary = _book.Worksheets[6];
..........
Aspose.Cells.Drawing.RadioButton radio = null;
 foreach (Shape item in _sheetSummary.Shapes)
            {

                if (item.GetType().ToString() == "Aspose.Cells.Drawing.RadioButton")
                {

                    radio = (Aspose.Cells.Drawing.RadioButton)item;


                    if (radio.Name.Contains("obs2"))
                    {
                        radio.IsChecked = true;


                    }


                }
            }
```

Hope, this helps a bit.